# What is the proper way to exit a WinForms application from static void Main() entry point

Tags: c#, winforms, exit

I know there are other questions about `Environment.Exit` but I would like the answer in respect to the specific set of facts described here.

What is the proper way to exit the `static void Main()` entry point of a WinForms application if the goals are to have the application shut down cleanly, free up all memory, and leave nothing in an unstable state. Is it as simple as `Environment.Exit(0)`?

```
 namespace MyApp
  {
    static class Program
    {

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
      bool authorized=false;
      authorized = Test(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
      if (!authorized)
        {
          MessageBox.Show("Sorry. Maybe next time.", 
         MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
          Environment.Exit(0);   //?
          
        }
       else
       {
          Application.Run(new Form1());
        } 
   
     }
   } 

 }
```

Comment: Have you tried ``this.Close();`` or just ``Close();``?

Comment: "free up all memory" - bear in mind that, no matter *how* a process exits, when the process ends, it's *address space* is destroyed and any memory which was being used by that address space is released. The era of thinking about processes allocating physical memory was the 80s.

Comment: @PrabhdeepSingh : It is not a matter of me "trying" anything. I'm not looking to experiment. I am looking for an authoritative answer to the question.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: does that also apply to code running in a virtualized environment, such as Citrix?  My main concern is not leaving things "hanging around", for example, if a stubborn unauthorized user tries to open the application a dozen times in rapid succession.

Comment: @PrabhdeepSingh `this` isn't a valid keyword in a static method (except as an _argument_ to an extension method).

Comment: The only obvious problem in that situation (other than why you're building security checks into the application like this) is one of your own making - you don't even try to exit the process until the user acknowledges a message box.

Comment: @Tim If a process exits but the memory it held isn't freed, that is a problem with the OS.

Comment: @Llama Oh thanks for the clarification, I was just confirming if he has tried it or not. Seems like ``Close();`` won't work.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : that was just me being quick and dirty when asking the question here. In actual code the message is acknowledged. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that can happen in your code as written:

1. `Test`, whatever it does, returns `false`; your code shows a MessageBox. You don't need to do anything else, no `Environment.Exit` etc, just show the messagebox; the app will quit when they click OK, because there is nothing stopping the code flow from leaving Main (other than the messagebox being open)
2. `Test` returns `true`, your app runs and shows `Form1`. The app will quit when Form1 closes, because `Application.Run` will return.

There's nothing magic about winforms apps Main method; it's the fact that Application.Run doesn't return while the form passed into it is still open that prevents the app from exiting. In the case where you don't open Form1, you open a MessageBox instead, which also blocks the execution flow until it is dismissed

Comment: Thanks for the information. On further reading of the docs, I don't know if my code will be allowed to call unmanaged code (which Environment.Exit() requires). So the question, if I were to rephrase it, is whether I should have `return` or `Application.Exit(); return;` after the MessageBox.  Is there any benefit (or downside) to issuing an Application.Exit() before returning out of the main entry point?

Comment: Why do you think you need either? `return` is redundant because the very next thing the code does is drop out of the `if`, reach the end of `Main` and return from it. `Application.Exit` is unnecessary because there aren't any opened windows that need to be given a chance to clean up after themselves.. Perhaps of greater significance in this is asking whether you plan to start any threads and, if so, why you aren't planning on making them background ones?

Comment: Do developers have to worry about cleaning up *anything* when bailing out of the main entry point of the app with `return` or Environment.Exit(0)? The user-authorization was a barebones example of needing to bail. There could be other reasons. Let's say I had issued multiple queries one after the other, each one closing a briefly-opened SQL Server connection in a `finally{}` block. I am not sure how and when the closing of a connection is sent from the client to the server so the connection can be returned to the pool.  Does exiting abruptly interfere with that?  Are "message pumps" involved?

Comment: By and large I think we can chalk that all up to "the operating system's problem" - don't worry; it does a reasonable job. In the specific example given, there would be no more pool, no more app, and maybe some TCP connections lingering that the OS has to sort out. Or may'be the pool is some part of the OS, but if you think about it, it's still not your problem; you've done your bit by quitting..